# My php script is connected, but android studio won't use it. No visible error outputs

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I have a php script for handling very basic registration. its in a folder in my localhost; http://(ipaddress/localhost):3306/testing/Register.php. Android studio points to this URL but i get no error output when i run the emulator. When i open the PHP script in the browser, everything looks good.

Here is the registerrequest java script:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://(ipaddress/localhost):3306/testing/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

here is my createuser script

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
        this.setTitle("Create User");
        final EditText username1 = findViewById(R.id.Createusername);
        final EditText password1 = findViewById(R.id.CreatePassword);
        final Switch isAdmin = findViewById(R.id.isadmin);
        final Button createuser = findViewById(R.id.createuserbtn);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response")){
            isAdmin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

finally, here is my PHP script, Register; m

```
$db_host = 'localhost:3306';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'test';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,'user',$db_pass,$db_name);
if($con){
    echo "connection successful";
}else{
    echo "connection failed";
}

$age = $_POST["isAdmin"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO cresidentials (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
if(!$statement) { printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }
if(!$statement) { return json_encode(['status'=>'failed','message'=>mysqli_error($con)]); }
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssi",$username,$password,$isAdmin);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
if(mysqli_error($statement)) { return json_encode(['status'=>'failed','message'=>mysqli_error($con)]); }

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Im using xampp (apache and mysql turned on) and my Register is in a folder in Htdocs. 
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I want to also point out; i do not see any app-crashing errors in logcat or run. Is it possible im not looking for the right error? or have it highlighted correctly? tbh, im just looking for a chunk of red text in logcat

Comment: seems to me that port 3306 on the URL is quite fishy : that's the default MySQL port.  Check your apache logs, php logs, etc. In your apache configs, you can increase the Loglevel.  Also, you have no error recovery code, nor logging. Do you even know whether the script is invoked by apache ?  Is php even enabled in your Apache server ?? etc ...

Comment: How exactly are you expecting this script to run, and on what (logical) computer?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Ill check the XAMMP for any logs regarding apache and mysql. I have no error code on Android's side, and when i open the php file in a browser. I do not know what you mean if PHP is enabled in my apache server, or any of those question. I simple turned on Apache and MySQL in XAMMP and went from there. This script runs on the localhost btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify constructor of `RegisterRequest`:

```
 public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, 
        Response.Listener<String> listener,
        Response.ErrorListener() errListener){ //add error listener

   super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,errListener);
   ......

 }
```

And in `CreateUser` class file, add below:

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Then:

```
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,
         responseListener,errorListener);
```

Now, run again and when error occured, you could see it in error listener.

Comment: this all fits in perfectly except the context in the toast. ill try to fix it here